# Show different number in twilio call REST API creating calls

Tags: php, twilio, phone-number, phone-call, twilio-api

Imagine that I'm creating a new call with REST API and set the parameters like this:

```
$client->account->calls->create("+15017250604", "+14155551212", $urlCallback);
```

When the phone rings, I don't wanna show the `+15017250604` as the caller, but I wanna show a different number. How can I do that?

Comment: so you want to lie?

Comment: It's not a lie, it's just a little fix in the final user interface. I make the call to a seller man that is redirected to a client, so he should see the client number instead of twillio number, you know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [FAQ](https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/voice/how-do-i-add-a-verified-outgoing-caller-id-with-twilio) to add a verified outgoing caller id.

To use the REST API, POST your phone number to the [Outgoing Caller IDs list resource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/outgoing-caller-ids).

Here's an example to add a new Outgoing Caller ID in PHP:

```
<?php
// Get the PHP helper library from twilio.com/docs/php/install
require_once('/path/to/twilio-php/Services/Twilio.php'); // Loads the library

// Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/user/account
$sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$client = new Services_Twilio($sid, $token);

$caller_id = $client->account->outgoing_caller_ids->create("+14158675309", array(
        "FriendlyName" => "My Home Phone Number"
    ));
echo $caller_id->validation_code;
```

Comment: The problem is that the "to" parameter isn't registered in my twilio account. So, how would I change that?